Pipe synchronization
So after being refered to this thread and also this thread linked to in the first thread, I still have no solution to my issue.
The Goal
To make alterations to both stderr and stdout, but maintain their original printing order.
Solutions
The one that I started out with and which is refered to the most, is the following.
command > >(sed 's/.../.../')
       2> >(sed 's/.../.../' >&2)

This as it turns out causes some race conditions and various portential asynchronous issues. And the order is not garanteed.
From the two thread mentioned above, there are some pipe solutions.
{ { "$@" | sed 's/.../.../' >&3; } 2>&1 \
         | sed 's/.../.../' >&2; } 3>&1

The pipe solution is elegant, but it does not maintain the order of the output. It will print stdout and then stderr. This is what everyone refers to as a synchronos solution, but "storing" stderr while printing stdout before dumping all of stderr at the end, is not really a proper synchronos solution.
fnc() {
    echo "This is GOOD text"
    echo "This is ERROR text" >&2
    
    echo "This is GOOD text"
    echo "This is ERROR text" >&2
    
    echo "This is GOOD text"
    echo "This is ERROR text" >&2
}

echo "Running test"
{ { fnc | sed 's/\(.*\)/  \1/' >&3; } 2>&1 \
         | sed 's/\(.*\)/  \1/' >&2; } 3>&1

This will output:
Running test
  This is GOOD text
  This is GOOD text
  This is GOOD text
  This is ERROR text
  This is ERROR text
  This is ERROR text

A solution like command 2>&1 |  cannot possibly be the only way to do this? Is there no way to maintain both streams while keeping the order in sync?

which should have been Why? If you run a command in the background, it can output right away, it can output in a week, it's in the background. What exactly is not "correct" in the output? In other words, the output is unsynchronized with the rest of the script. If you want to wait for the background process to finish executing, you can wait on it.

Does this answer your question? Bash process substitution and syncing. If not, it is for sure related.

@kvantour While this reading is interesting, this does not answer to the question because.. the OP does not even use process substitution.

@vdavid true, but the answer also deals with asynchronous processes and this is exactly what is going on here.

@kvantour That is correct, but the OP doesn't seem to comprehend that there's an asynchronous issue to begin with. If you can re-open the issue, I believe I can provide helpful information to the OP.

Let me first say, I am not new to asynchronous tasks. I use this all the time in real programming languages. But Bash is not that familiar to be and to be honest, uses some strange syntax where it reused characters a lot for different meanings. I found this example ones that I added to a larger script without worrying about how it worked. The test script was the beginning of me trying to actually learn how this trick worked and it does work in my real script.

I hit the character limit, so I will continue. The link provided to me tells me that my previous success was simply a matter of the right race conditions. More code meant that everything had more time to finish. So the real issue with my example is that it's to simple :D  The race condition aspect of it is why I was bothered. The damn thing had been working for me the past year without issues in a large cron script. Then for some reason it just don't in another script. So thanks for the link, I did try looking for similar examples, but without the right keywords, it's not always easy.

@dbergloev Since I can't write a full-fledged answer, I'll sum up real quick (too quick, maybe). What you are asking cannot be done as long as 1. your messages are output in separate processes, and 2. those processes are running asynchronously. To make sure they are written in a controlled order, you either need to 1. remove asynchronous output, or 2. synchronize background processes. The latter is quite complex and kind of breaks the benefits of having background processes in the first place, so I would recommend to avoid that.
